# Conflict of interest with the job interviewer

Tags: interviewing, manager

I was working as CM on short term position for 6 years. Company announced long term position on same job where I am participating. There was disciplinary investigation before on some minor issue where head of HR and my line manager were involved.  I am claiming this disciplinary sanction in the court at the moment, against HR manager and line manager.

I have interview on a permanent position where my line manager (the one against who i have claim in the civil court as he was head of disciplinary panel ) is the interviewer.
Is my manager in conflict of interest in this case during the interview ?

Comment: So, in brief, you don't like the company and then apply for a different post... So is this your conflict of interest? Are you looking for your next court case?

Comment: This person will be your manager, if you can't get on with them in an interview what makes you think you'll be a good fit for part of their team, being managed by them?

Comment: So you're suing the company and the manager over some previous action and now you're applying for another position with that same manager? Why?

Answer (score 5):

Conflict of interests does not apply in the employment scenario, unfortunately. Conflict of interests usually only applies to public funds and in areas of civic responsibility such as political posts etc. 
Companies and businesses do not need to be transparent or publically accountable. They have all the various rights to privacy that will make your situation difficult to navigate, unfortunately. Small businesses in small towns would especially run into difficulties if such a law exist. Most people are very well connected and there would be near impossible to find a person without any conflicts. 
So unless there is evidence of blatant discrimination under one of the mandated discrimination laws, I don't think you will have much room to appeal or question any decisions.

Having said all that, is there a moral (edited:social) conflict of interest, yes! Most people off the street would agree that having a legal case against a manager who is then interviewing you would definitely be a massive a conflict of interest.

Comment: So legal: no  
moral: yes

Comment: Moral is a better phrase. Thanks Borgh. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the interviewer will be fair to you. The only way you get the job is if a third party knows you'll do extremely well and vouches for you strongly and has significant influence at this company. But frankly, how can you stomach the interview one-on-one with someone you had to take to court to resolve a previous issue? Plus HR is the department you would have to go through to ask for a different interviewer. Why are they interviewing you? Are you the only candidate? If so, just go through it and get the job. Then, hopefully you are at a large company and never have to deal with these individuals again.